# Google Drive sync stops if internet goes down

Tags: google-drive

I am trying to sync some shared folders on Google Drive that I downloaded to my desktop.

When electricity is cut or internet goes down suddenly, does the sync start over or it starts from where it has stopped?

Answer (score 1):

According to people on the [Google Drive support forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/drive/apldnebXBAg), the sync will start from where the files weren't synced. The files that were synced won't be synced again.

Comment: I think this should confirm what I said: 

http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/drive/apldnebXBAg

Comment: Thanks. Next time, please [edit] your answer to include the information. Comments are, by their nature, impermanent.